Build failed with an exception in google sign in app
I'm trying to add google sign-in to my app but this error occurs when I try to run on android.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.


Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.7.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.7.1.pom
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I've tried to solve it but couldn't.

Share project's build.gradle file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i have a discord channel that solves this problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
